# List Item of Recyclerview will be pushed to next item after removing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have an Recyclerview with products. Each product has a notice which you can add via AlertDialog. After removing an item, the next item will get the notice of the removed item if it has no own one. This is probably somehow related to a reference. But I dont know where. I tried to create a new product item instead of make products[position] but it didnt work.

Here is my onBindViewHolder:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val product = products[position]

        //render
        val imgUrl = BASE_IMG_URL + product.images.small[0]
        Glide.with(viewHolder.image.context).load(imgUrl).into(viewHolder.image)

        viewHolder.title.text = product.name
        viewHolder.subtitle.text = product.prodid
        viewHolder.quantity.text = product.quantity.toString()

        viewHolder.close.setOnClickListener {
            products.removeAt(position)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
            viewModel.updateProducts(products)
        }

        viewHolder.cart_product_add_notice.setOnClickListener {
            showProductNoticeDialog(it, product, viewHolder)
        }

        if(product.notice.isNotEmpty()) {
            if(product.notice.length >= 20) {
                viewHolder.cart_product_notice.text = product.notice.substring(0,30) + "..."
            } else {
                viewHolder.cart_product_notice.text = product.notice
            }
        }
    }
```

The function showProductNoticeDialog() will handle the setOnClickListener:

```
fun showProductNoticeDialog(view: View, product: ProductCart, viewHolder: ViewHolder) {
        // get alert_dialog.xml view
        val li = LayoutInflater.from(view.context)
        val promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_product_notice, null)

        val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(
            view.context
        )

        // set alert_dialog.xml to alertdialog builder
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView)

        val alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create()

        val userInput = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.alert_user_input) as EditText

        if(product.notice.isNotEmpty()) {
            userInput.setText(product.notice)
            userInput.setSelection(userInput.text.length)
        }

        val okayBtn = promptsView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_alert_dialog_notice_okay)
        val cancelBtn = promptsView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_alert_dialog_notice_cancel)

        okayBtn.setOnClickListener {
            product.notice = userInput.text.toString()

            if(userInput.text.length >= 20) {
                viewHolder.cart_product_notice.text = userInput.text.substring(0, 30) + "..."
            } else {
                viewHolder.cart_product_notice.text = userInput.text
            }

            alertDialog.cancel()
        }

        cancelBtn.setOnClickListener { alertDialog.cancel() }

        alertDialog.show()
    }
```

I hope someone could help me :)

Comment: The `RecyclerView` _recycles_ views. That's its job. So in your bind you should take it into account, and setup the views accordingly: i.e. you are setting the notice only when it is not empty, but you should also reset it if it is empty, otherwise you'll show the one from the recycled view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @gpunto in the comment, the `RecyclerView` is reusing the same view after you update the list. The solution in this case is to set the notice to empty if not present, in order to clear it out in case it was set before

```
    if(product.notice.isNotEmpty()) {
        if(product.notice.length >= 20) {
            viewHolder.cart_product_notice.text = product.notice.substring(0,30) + "..."
        } else {
            viewHolder.cart_product_notice.text = product.notice
        }
    }
    else {
            viewHolder.cart_product_notice.text = ""
    }
```